# redirect from old mod-write to new one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I had a mod re-write all set up for a client who was hosting their site on a shared server with GoDaddy.  After nearly of year of working they contacted me and GoDaddy had changed something that made the re-write not work properly.  It would work sometimes but not all the time.  Anywway, it liked nice URLs such as `http://siteurl.com/employee/19/` as opposed to `http://siteurl.com/employee-19` from what I was reading it had something to do with it not ending in a slash but either way, the first one works now.

However is there a way to create a redirect from the old modrewrite rule to the new one.  I tried this but had never really done rewrites on the htaccess file before so I could have set it up wrong.

`redirect /employee-19 http://siteurl.com/employee/19/`

But that spits back an error 301, any thoughts on how to fix this or is it just a lost cause at this point?

Answer (score 0):

> But that spits back an error 301, any thoughts on how to fix this or is it just a lost cause at this point?

A 301 is what you want. It tells browsers and search engine indexing bots that `http://siteurl.com/employee-19` is equivalent to `http://siteurl.com/employee/19/` but to use the latter from now on. The content has *permanently moved from the first to the second URL*.

If you want a more generalized form, you can use `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/employee-([0-9]+) http://siteurl.com/employee/$1/
```

Comment: Correct, but is there a way to make it redirect to the second url, I do not want the error page, I want it to forward to the second url

Comment: @ChrisJamesChampeau I don't understand, 301 isn't an error, it is a *redirect*.

Comment: Got it, had an error document built for it based on a php code that would throw any error into an error page regardless of the error...fixed that the right way